# Abstract class member variable

Tags: c++

I have an abstract class, `CAbstract`, and want to have a member of this type in another class, `CClass`. If I make it a pointer, I will have to take care of the deleting myself, and do would like to avoid this.

- If I make it a reference, will it get deleted automatically when the `CClass` gets deleted?
- Can I make it a `shared_ptr`? Can `shared_ptr` manage abstract classes and pointing to derived classes?

Comment: A reference have to be referencing something. I recommend `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I was going to provide a temporary to the constructor for the reference.

Comment: That's one reason you can't use references in this case. Once set a reference can't be changed.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I don't want it changed. It will be supplied to the constructor of `CClass` and then stay unchanged through the life of the `CClass`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

References don't automatically deallocate anything; `shared_ptr` does. As long as you follow the rules of C++, it should handle inheritance situations gracefully. More specifically, since `shared_ptr`'s destructor calls `delete` by default when the reference count drops to zero, you need to implement the (`virtual`) destructor properly to make `shared_ptr` work.